# Solving 2nd degree ODE with Euler method in MATLAB

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I am trying to solve the equation below;

$$\ddot{x}= -x + sin(t)$$

by the initial conditions;

$$x(0) = 0 \\ \dot{x}(0)= 0$$

my MATLAB code is as follows:

```
clc
clear all

%define time step and tend

dt = 0.01;
tf = 1.0;

%create arrays for tvec, xvec and uvec

tvec = 0:dt:tf;
xvec = zeros(length(tvec),1);
xvec(1) = 0;
uvec = zeros(length(tvec),1);
uvec(1) = 0;

%run euler
for i = 1:length(tvec)-1
    xvec(i+1) = xvec(i) + dt*uvec(i);
    uvec(i+1) = uvec(i) + dt*(-xvec(i)+sin(i+1));
end
```

but this code gives me the solution at $x(1.0)$ wrong. Where am I being failed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try this:

```
tf = 5;
Nt = 150;
dt = tf/Nt;

t = 0:dt:tf;

x0 = 0;
u0 = 0;

x = zeros(Nt+1,1);
u = x;

x(1) = x0;
u(1) = u0;

for i = 1:Nt;

    u(i+1) = u(i) + dt*(-x(i)+sin(t(i)));
    x(i+1) = x(i) + dt*u(i);

end

plot(t,x,t,u,'k');
legend('x(t)','u(t)');
```

You use the RHS of the equation at the time $t_i$ because you are using an explicit or forward Euler's scheme. An alternative for improving consistence would be computing $x_{i+1}$ with the information of $u$ at the time $i+1$, i.e:

```
x(i+1) = x(i) + dt*u(i+1);
```

You can check that there are some differences but don't expect big changes. You can derive a matrix-form system of equations for a backward or implicit scheme in order to solve the unknowns of: $g(x_{n+1},u_{n+1},t_{n+1}) = f(x_n,u_n)$.

Cheers!

Comment: thank you Dmoreno! I was placing the counter in the $sin$  function as you mentioned..

Comment: @Dmoreno: You `for` loop should be from `1` to `Nt`. Fixing that may require changing other things.

Comment: Of course, the counter is wrong, but note that this doesn't affect much since I initialized the state vector to zero. Thanks for noting this! On the other hand, you're welcome @Yirmidokuz. Glad this helps!

Comment: Edited my comment. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use **sin(dt*(i))** or **sin(dt*(i+1))**, not sin(i+1).
2. This is a first order method, so don't expect to be very close.

Comment: how should I decide to choose sin(dt*(i)) or sin(dt*(i+1)) ?

Comment: I am already multiplying sin(i+1) with $\text{dt}$, as $...+dt*(-xvec(i)+sin(i+1))$

Comment: Note that you are now evaluating $\sin{i}$ where $i$ is a counter. You must compute $\sin{t}$ at $t = t_i$ or, in Matlab notation, $\text{sin(t(i))}$. You might evaluate it at $i+1$ as well.

Comment: @Yirmidokuz - As noted by Dmoreno, you should evaluate the sine at t(i), not at i. As to accuracy - it doesn't make any big difference whether you use sin(t(i)) or sin(t(i+1)). The method is first order in either case and the stability of the method is not affected by this choice.